# How to add an atom:link element to an RSS XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml, rss, simplexml

I'm creating the XML for my RSS feed programatically in PHP.

It's all good except for one thing - I can't create the `<atom:link>` element correctly.

With any other element, this works:

```
$channel->addChild('title', "My Blog");
```

But when I try this...

```
$channel->addChild('atom:link');
```

...it creates a `<link>` element and not the expected `<atom:link>`. I've tried adding the `atom` part as a namespace but that just creates `<link xlmns='atom'>` instead.

How can I do this?

Comment: `atom` is just the local prefix (it could really be any other word of your choice). You still need to define the namespace URI, which is what really counts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a third parameter as the namespace where atom:link is available.

```
$root->addChild('atom:link','','http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
```

[Addchild Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php)